# Automated APK publish to Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I maintain a suite of Android applications, all of which are built using Maven to have their own APK files. These get uploaded manually to the Android Market via the publisher web UI.

Periodically, I'll update a common library component that all the applications use, and I'll re-build all the applications that depend on it, resulting in a suite of new APKs. What I then need to do is publish all of these updated APKs to the Market.

Doing this for many applications at once is time-consuming - I would really like a way to automate the process.

Does anybody know of a way to publish a 'Market-ready' (i.e. already packaged, signed, zipaligned etc.) APK to my account in the Android Market in a scriptable fashion? I can upload from *nix or Windows platforms. Extra credit if there's a nice way to wire this into a Maven build.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since there is no documented and supported API for the Android Market, let alone its submission process, any solution you get will be inherently unreliable.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare - I'm sure you're right, but I'd settle for a partial solution if it saves some time.

Comment: The only way I can think of it to write something yourself using HTMLUnit to automate the process.